# c# login Google App Engine (GAE) returns http 500

Tags: c#, google-app-engine

c# login Google App Engine (GAE) returns http 500
c# google-app-engine http-status-code-500

---

I want to retrive user specific data form the app engine with a c# client. The Client uses the following code to authenticate:

```
private const string GoogleLoginUri = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
private const string AppBaseUri = "http://sphinx-online.appspot.com/";
private const string AppLoginUri = AppBaseUri + "_ah/login";
private const string AppMyStarredQuestionnaireUri = AppBaseUri + "res/MyStarredQuestionnaires";

[...]

private static void RetrieveAuthToken(SyncStorage syncStorage)
{
    // Request
    HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(GoogleLoginUri);
    authRequest.Method = "POST";
    authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    authRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    String postData = string.Format("Email={0}&Passwd={1}&service={2}&source={3}&accountType={4}",
        Uri.EscapeUriString(syncStorage.Username),
        Uri.EscapeUriString(syncStorage.Password),
        Uri.EscapeUriString("apps"),
        Uri.EscapeUriString("lippodesign-sphinx-1.0"),
        Uri.EscapeUriString("GOOGLE"));

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    authRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

    using (Stream postDataStr = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        postDataStr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        postDataStr.Flush();
    }


    // Response
    HttpWebResponse authResponse = (HttpWebResponse)authRequest.GetResponse();

    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(authResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            String line = responseReader.ReadLine();

            if (line == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (line.StartsWith("Auth="))
            {
                syncStorage.AuthToken = line.Substring(5);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void RetrieveCookie(SyncStorage syncStorage)
{
    Uri cookieRequestUrl = new Uri(string.Format("{0}?auth={1}", AppLoginUri, syncStorage.AuthToken));

    HttpWebRequest cookieRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(cookieRequestUrl);
    cookieRequest.Method = "GET";
    cookieRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    cookieRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    using (HttpWebResponse cookieResponse = (HttpWebResponse)cookieRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        syncStorage.Cookie = cookieResponse.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
    }
}

private static void RetrieveData(SyncStorage syncStorage)
{
    Uri dataRequestUrl = new Uri(AppMyStarredQuestionnaireUri);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(dataRequestUrl);
    request.Headers["Cookie"] = syncStorage.Cookie;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            syncStorage.JsonData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

All works fine for a while, but since I try it before two days I always get an http-error-code 500 (Internal Error) when I want to get the cookie (RetrieveCookie-Method). I think it does not work since I activate 2-Step-Authentication. The Google ClientLogin for Installed Applications says:

> Important: If any of your customers are having trouble with ClientLogin, their account may not be compatible with it for a variety of possible reasons. For example, accounts that use 2-step verification, SAML, or Open ID are not compatible with ClientLogin. One workaround is to tell users to generate a single-use password, provided by access codes, which allows them to log in to their account in a web browser and generate a long password that they can type into the password field of any application using ClientLogin. A better solution is to convert your app to use OAuth 2.0, which is compatible with all existing Google accounts.

I use an **Application-specific password** for login. Before I get a http-error 403 "Authentication failed" while getting the auth-token.

I have no idea why I can't retrieve the cookie. Getting the auth-token works fine.

And the Webservice has no problem, I can call it over a browser without having trouble if I am loggend in.

Comment: Are there any hints in the server logs?

Comment: What page gives you the 500? What are you sending to it? What do your App Engine logs say about the request?

Comment: There are no login-specific entries in the App Engine logs.

Comment: oh ... enter adds the comment directly ^^

I send an empty request with the following url:
http://sphinx-online.appspot.com/_ah/login?auth=<AuthToken>

The cookieRequest throws an WebException:
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.